# Style centerPadding in slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

How can I style the centerPadding in the slick.js slider? I want set the opacity of the padding, but not all items in the track.

```
$('.ourgroup-carousel').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding:'80px',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a css class ".slick-center" that references the current centered div. Feel free to jazz up the center div as you wish by putting that in your own stylesheet.

Comment: that styles just center div,question was how to style centerPadding:''80px'', not center div in track.That property are the first and the last div with partial visibility in slick track.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is a really old question, but i stumbled across the same problem lately, my fix was to use following css

```
.slick-slide[aria-hidden="true"] {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

it will in fact style all invisible slides, but as they are not shown it doesn't matter.